# Is there a possible way to reload section header view separate from the table cells in tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've tried to use

```
[_tableView reloadSections:<#(NSIndexSet *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>];
```

But it will reload the table cells belong to the section which I don't want.

I also tried to provide the section header view by

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and I keep a reference. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `viewForHeaderInSection` or is the typo in your code? If you have a reference to the section header view and you modify the view, it should update in the table. If you make a change that the view can't recognize as requiring a redraw, you may have to call `[headerView setNeedsDisplay]`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo.I've confirmed it again and it works.Maybe I really forget to `setNeedsDisplay`. Thank you very much!